# Cast string as array

Tags: javascript

How, in Javascript, can I cast a string as an array in the same way that PHP (array) does.

```
//PHP
$array = (array)"string"
```

Basically I have a variable that can be an array or a string and, if a string, I want to make it an array using an inline command.

Comment: I don't believe there is casting in JavaScript.

Comment: There is casting in JS but it is seldom used (just like in PHP). A common use is to treat a number as a string or a string as a number. "1" + "1" = "11" if you are not careful.

Comment: You want to make it an Array of what? Should it be an Array of individual characters in the string? Or an Array that has the entire string at its first index?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

JavaScript is a prototyping language and does not have a type casting system.

One solution would be to check if your variable is a string and convert it into an array. For example :

```
if (typeof someVariable === 'string') someVariable = [someVariable];
```

In PHP, if you do a check on a **string**, like (ex: `$array = 'string';`) :

```
$array = (array) $array;  // ex: "string" becomes array("string")
```

The JavaScript equivalent will be

```
arr = typeof arr === 'string' ? [arr] : arr;
```

If your variable `arr` is not necessarily a string, you may use `instanceof` (*edit: or `Array.isArray`*) :

```
arr = arr instanceof Array ? arr : [arr];
arr = Array.isArray(arr) ? arr : [arr];
```

Answer (score 42):

Hacky, but works:

```
[].concat(arrayOrString);

//Usage:
[].concat("a");
//["a"]
[].concat(["a"]);
//["a"]
```

Comment: [Note] This is rather slow compared to the alternative: http://jsperf.com/array-coerce

Comment: @Metalstorm Was it used in the same way? jsperf is currently down and I cannot check.

Comment: @JeromeJ yes, it compares `concat` with `Array.isArray()`. The difference is noticeable.

Comment: @Zim Ah thanks! Way faster indeed but sadly less beautiful: `Array.isArray(obj) ? obj:[obj]`

Comment: This was the only solution I could find that would allow me to transform a string property to array inside a foreach statement. `([].concat(foo.bar.stringOrArray)).forEach((item) => {...})`

Answer (score 7):

```
var str    = "string";
var array  = str.split('');

console.log(array); // ['s', 't', 'r', 'i','n','g']
```

Comment: in PHP doing `str = (array)"string"` results in `array("string")` not `array('s','t','r','i','n','g')`.

Comment: Any way I was looking for ['s', 't', 'r', 'i','n','g'] from "string". THX

Comment: `str_split($my_string)` in PHP btw.

Comment: If that's what you want (and not what the OP was asking for), then just use `Array.from()` see MDN notes [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from]

Answer (score 4):

You can in jQuery...

```
var arr = "[1,2,3,4,5]"; 
window.x = $.parseJSON(arr);
console.log(x);//cast as an array...
```

it works even if you have something like

```
[{"key":"value"}]
```

However this may NOT work if you have something like this...

```
[{key:"value"}] // different is the " (double quotes) on key
```

Comment: You don't need jQuery for that (Any more) , JSON.parse(arr); works the same.

Answer (score 3):

Turn a string into an array:

```
var myString = "['boop','top','foo']";
var myArray = JSON.parse(myString)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do like this

```
"sample".split("");
```

and you'll get

```
["s", "a", "m", ...]
```

Comment: If you have something like: "[10,20,34,0]" and you want it to be: [10,20,34,0], your solution won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast to Array in JS but a simple ternary operation can do what you want.

```
var str = 'string';
var arr = (str instanceof Array) ? str : [ str ];
```

This works for any non-Array object or any primitive value. If you're sure that only actual `Array` objects and `string` primitives can be encountered here, the following is a bit faster:

```
var arr = (typeof str === 'string') ? [ str ] : str;
```

Comment: How does it compare with `Array.isArray(str) ? str:[str]`?

Comment: **Update:** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22289727/difference-between-using-array-isarray-and-instanceof-array > `Array.isArray` is a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

```
"1,2,3".split(",") 
=> ["1", "2", "3"]
```

use split()

Comment: this is not the PHP equivalent asked in the question

Answer (score 0):

Val's suggestion also works for strings which have array of arrays

```
var str = "[[1121,1],[1122,2],[1123,3]]";
var arr = $.parseJSON(str);
console.log(arr); //returns array of arrays
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following if statement:

```
if(array instanceof Array != true) {array = [array];}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.isArray(foo) || (foo = [foo]);
```

or if that's not comfortable

```
foo = Array.isArray(foo) ? foo : [foo];
```

Answer (score -2):

There is already [a proposal](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-flatMap/) for `Array.flatten()` and usable with `babel-preset-stage-2`.

```js
const array = ['foo'].flatten()
console.log(array) // ['foo']

const array = [['foo', 'bar']].flatten()
console.log(array) // ['foo', 'bar']
```