# Difference between using Array.isArray and instanceof Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

There is two ways to figure out if an array is an array or an object. Using `typeof item === "object";` will return true for an object and an array since arrays are relatively new to javascript and arrays are prototypes of objects(may have worded this wrong, feel free to correct me). So the two ways I know of to determine if an Array is an Array are:

Solution 1:

```
Array.isArray(item);
```

Solution 2:

```
item instanceof Array;
```

My questions are:

1. What is the difference between these two solutions?
2. Which of these two is the preferred solution?
3. Which has a faster process time?

Comment: possible duplicate of [which is the best method used for checking isarray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19196539/which-is-the-best-method-used-for-checking-isarray)

Comment: `isArray` is more generic. It works across iframes, which `isntanceof` does not. It also looks like that `isArray` will correctly recognize typed arrays in ES6.

Comment: I’m sticking to `instanceof Array`, because: 1. the syntax is consistent with `instanceof (other classes)`, 2. for my Node.js, `Array`s and instances extending `Array` are constructed by the same `Array` in the same _execution context_.

Comment: @FelixKling, you said “_`isArray` will correctly recognize typed arrays_,” but on my Chrome 107, `Array.isArray(new Uint8Array)` is `false`.

Comment: @КонстантинВан You are correct, it doesn't look like it covers typed arrays.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

> 1.What is the difference between these two solutions?

[*isArray*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.3.2) is an ES5 method so not supported by older browsers, but it reliably determines if an object is an Array.

[*instanceof*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.6) only checks if *Array.prototype* is on an object's `[[Prototype]]` chain. It fails when checking arrays across frames since the *Array* constructor used for the instance will likely be different to the one used for the test.

> 2.Which of these two is the preferred solution?

"Preferred" assumes some criterion for selection. Generally, the preferred method is something like:

```
if (Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) == '[object Array]')
```

which suits ES3 browsers and works across frames. If only ES5 browsers are in consideration, *isArray* is likely OK.

> 3.Which has a faster process time?

Largely irrelevant, since the processing time for both is negligible. Far more important to select the one that is reliable. An *Array.isArray* method can be added to browsers that don't have it built–in using:

```
if (!Array.isArray) {
    Array.isArray = function(obj) {
      return Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) == '[object Array]';
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't triple equals `===` be more reliable?

Comment: @vad—No. *Object.prototype.toString* always returns a string, so the results for `==` and `===` are identical.

Comment: Do note that in ES6+, an object may give itself a custom `toStringTag` resulting in `[object Array]` despite not actually being an array. I'm not sure if a fully reliable polyfill is possible for `Array.isArray`

Comment: @CertainPerformance—sure, but the above only suggests using a pollyfill where *Array.isArray* is not available, which excludes ECMAScript 2015 (introduced 4 years after ES5 and *isArray*) and later.

Comment: > "Largely irrelevant, since the processing time for both is negligible."
That depends on how much you're calling these methods. In some context, e.g. games performance is ultra important.

Comment: @HankMoody—if you're coding for speed, then *isArray* should be avoided altogether, or at least called very infrequently. Also, performance should be tested across multiple implementations as it varies greatly.

Comment: I could argue though, that even if in a case `==` and `===` are identical, the latter still must be used. I mean, we dont choose selectively safety guidelines based on where we think they fit. We put them everywhere to form a habit, just in case something is forgotten, for a case we didnt think could happen or anything stupid happens. **It's not good practice to be selective with good practices, they should be applied everywhere or dont use them at all.**

Comment: @Eksapsy— "must"? I think the fact that there are 73 answers covering more than a decade to [*Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons) indicates it's a moot point. Just use one or the other consistently, and if strong typing is required, use Typescript. There is no evidence that `===` is "safer" than `==`.

Comment: @RobG, Eksapsy started with "I could argue", so why focus on his use of the word "must"? You statement "There is no evidence", though... What do you even mean with "evidence" when every frickin resource you can find on `==`/`===` talks about `==`'s ambiguity and how the operator is a mistake in the language. Isn't "**People being affected by the damn thing**" evidence to you? Just say "I don't see how" instead of "There is no evidence that", makes you look less discourteous...

Answer (score 47):

1. **Difference between `Array.isArray(item)` and `item instanceof Array`**

   As Felix Kling mentioned in the comment, `instanceof Array` doesn't work across iframes. To give you a specific example, try the following code:

   ```
   var iframeEl = document.createElement('iframe');
   document.body.appendChild(iframeEl);
   iframeArray = window.frames[window.frames.length - 1].Array;

   var array1 = new Array(1,1,1,1);
   var array2 = new iframeArray(1,1,1,1);

   console.log(array1 instanceof Array);  // true    
   console.log(Array.isArray(array1));  // true

   console.log(array2 instanceof Array);  // false    
   console.log(Array.isArray(array2));  // true
   ```

   As you see in the example above, array created with the Array constructor in iframe (i.e. `array2`) is not recognized as an array when you use `instanceof Array`. However, it is correctly identified as an array when using `Array.isArray()`.

   If you are interested in knowing why `instanceof Array` doesn't work across different globals (i.e. `iframe` or `window`), you can read more about it on [here](http://web.mit.edu/jwalden/www/isArray.html).
2. **Which of these two is the preferred solution?**

   In most cases `instanceof Array` should be enough. However, since `instanceof Array` doesn't work correctly across `iframes`/`window`, `Array.isArray()` would be more robust solution.

   Make sure to check for browser compatibility though. If you need to support IE 8 or less, `Array.isArray()` won't work (see [Mozilla's doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)).
3. **Which has a faster process time?**

   According to this [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/array-isarray-vs-instanceof-array), `instanceof Array` is faster than `Array.isArray()`. Which makes sense, because `Array.isArray()` performs more robust checking and therefore takes a slight performance hit.

Comment: Just came across this and would like to note that `Array.isArray()` in some browsers is now significantly faster than `instanceof Array`

Comment: Also, `instanceof Array` has a syntax consistent with `instanceof OtherClasses`. Unless you have multiple _execution contexts_, as in the browser environment, I recommend `instanceof Array` more.

Comment: Actually, results show that `instanceof Array` is actually the slowest way to check if the property is an array. While `Array.isArray` is the fastest by far. https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/ShowResult/441220