# How to check if x is an Object but not a String Object

Tags: javascript

What I have so far.

```
const isNotNullObject = function (x) {
    return (typeof x === "object" && x !== null);
};
```

It works fine for arrays and objects. But for String objects too !

```
isNotNullObject(String(5))
false
isNotNullObject(new String(5))
true
```

What I want is false for any type of string. Note that I don't have control of the calling code. I can't remove `new` myself. I need a solution that does not create a new String just to check for equality if possible for performance reasons.

Comment: Why not `typeof x == "object" && typeof x != "string"`?

Comment: What @ifvictr just said!

Comment: But string objects *are* objects. Treat them as such and assume that your caller knows not to wrap strings.

Comment: @ifvictr: If `typeof x == "object"` is `true`, then we already know `typeof x != "string"` is also `true`. The value of `typeof x` isn't going to change after the first comparison.

Comment: string objects are objects - Yes, a gimmick of the spec.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **[instance of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof)**

```
return (typeof x === "object" && !(x instanceof String) && x !== null)
```

```js
const isNotNullObject = function(x) {
  return (typeof x === "object" && !(x instanceof String) && x !== null);
};

console.log(
  isNotNullObject(String(5)),
  isNotNullObject(new String(5))
)
```

Comment: @Bergi : what you mean by frames

Comment: See http://perfectionkills.com/instanceof-considered-harmful-or-how-to-write-a-robust-isarray/ or http://stackoverflow.com/q/22289727/1048572

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to check type of Object/String/Array.

- using `type of X` operator using
- `Object.prototype.toString.apply(X)`

  //Its performance is worst
- `Object.getPrototypeOf(X)`
- X.constructor.

Where X can be Object/Array/String/Number or Anything. For performance Comparison Please see below image

[image]