# What is difference between Array.isArray and jQuery.isArray?

Tags: javascript, jquery

They seem to be the same.

**Internally *jQuery* just maps its own `$.isArray` to the native `Array.isArray`.***

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22289727/difference-between-using-array-isarray-and-instanceof-array

Comment: Maybe it's a compatibility thing. Try checking previous revisions of this function

Comment: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/1b9575b9d14399e9426b9eacdd92b3717846c3f2

Comment: @AlivetoDie Your link points to unrelated question. It seems to be similar, but it isn't. How it can help me?

Comment: @AlonEitan Probably. But why it isn't deprecated, if it just maps to a native function?

Comment: @VictorDombrovsky I don't actually know why. I can only guess that it's there for backwards compatibility reasons

Comment: @sotirios-delimanolis How this question may be opinion based? If there is any difference, then it may be clearly defined. No opinion is involved.

Comment: @VictorDombrovsky Please [read this](http://blog.jquery.com/2017/03/16/jquery-3-2-0-is-out/) (_Deprecated `jQuery.isArray`_)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After further investigation I found [this commit](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/1b9575b9d14399e9426b9eacdd92b3717846c3f2) where they replaced `jQuery.isArray` with the native [Array.isArray()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray).

They also announced [here](http://blog.jquery.com/2017/03/16/jquery-3-2-0-is-out/) that `$.isArray` is officially deprecated.

The function [still exist](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/deprecated.js#L37) for backward compatibility but I guess it will be dropped completly in a future jQuery release.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference.

jQuery just prototype the JavaScript's native `isArray` function.

something that will look like-

```
jQuery.prototype.isArray = Array.isArray;
```

Comment: OP is in confusion and it is OP's assumption that both are same. This answer confirming it. @AlivetoDie

Comment: For what reason? If it would be for backward compatibility, it should be marked as deprecated, but it isn't.