# js understanding arrow notation ternary operator

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator, arrow-functions

I have the following two functions:

```
const sections = Object.keys(this.state.obj).map(key => {console.log(key,'x')
  return({
  key,
  title: key,
  // turn array of values into array of objects in the shape {key, value}
  data: toArray(this.state.obj[key]).map(toObject),
})})

const toArray = val => val instanceof Array ? val : [val]
```

could someone explain what [val] is in the second function?  Why are the [] needed?

Comment: It's an array literal with a single element. Nothing to do with the ternary or arrow function syntax.

Comment: `function toArray(val) { if (val instanceof Array) return val; else return [val]; }`. Should've been `Array.isArray(val)` though.

Comment: ahh, so we are forcing the return to be an array

Comment: Yes, that's what the name `toArray` suggests :-)

Comment: why is Array.isArray() better than instanceof Array?

Comment: @DCR https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22289727/difference-between-using-array-isarray-and-instanceof-array