# TypeScript - Filter by Generic Type

Tags: typescript

I have an object which has some values which are arrays and some which are not. I want to filter out the arrays and I saw this being done in a similar way as following, but I want it to be done with all arrays and in cases when it's not of type instead of cases when it's of type, not just pass a specific type. Can it be done?

```
Object.values(inputsOptions).filter((obj: any): obj is not Array => {
        return obj instanceof Array;
    }).forEach(obj =>{
        //Every object has style property but arrays do not
        obj.style = {marginLeft: "1em"};
    });
```

Just noticed I used obj is Array when I meant the exact opposite, but I have now changed it. Still, the problem remains.

Comment: Please consider modifying the above code to constitute a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/OwEyVw) where others can demonstrate the issue for themselves.  That will increase the chance that any answer you get actually addresses the problem you're seeing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `is not` assertion in TypeScript, and also if there were, and `obj` is `any` but not `Array`, it does not mean it's an object with a style property.

If you *know* obj can only be an array or an object with a mutable `style` property, you can assert what you *do* have:

```
Object.values({})
  .filter((value: unknown): value is { style: unknown } => {
    return !Array.isArray(value);
  })
  .forEach((object) => {
    object.style = { marginLeft: "1em" };
  });
```

(Also you should use `Array.isArray` instead of `instanceof Array`, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22289727/difference-between-using-array-isarray-and-instanceof-array).)

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PIIwVgpgxgLgdANwIYBsCuEDOAKA3gXwEoBYAKAAJy4AzASxRggCdttl0IAuctAOwGteAewDuvQt3YZytTOVzlMMAJ4ouPAcLHl85ALwA+eWUqUmEGGia9yAQgCCTJkmVxZj58raoMhANwmOiQUVNRCTACiSFAAFqxC4NAwhPpGuIGUCZCwcEqqEPry5AC2SEwA5rS8ADIQ1DDcAEQAjBDFjToBIUR+QA)

Comment: Thank you! That's exatcly what I needed.